# jquery how to remove ui-state-focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

A use jquery and button used my style, but when i clicked on button style changed on ui-state-focus.
I try remove jquery style

```
$("button").mousedown(function () {
      $('button').removeClass("ui-state-focus");
});
```

but it not worked. How to remove jquery style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add removeClass in focus and worked for me.

```
$("button").focus(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this)` instead of `$('button')`

```
$("button").mousedown(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus");
});
```

Comment: remove ui-state-active worked, but not worked for ui-state-active

Comment: You can also try to use `click` event instead of `mousedown`.

Comment: @Namor, since you posted your code, some indications: when you use an element to referring something in jQuery, like this `$('a').click(function...` you're referring ALL the links in the DOM. This is also applied to `$('button')`, etc.. try mixing the calls with CSS classes like this: `<a class="mylink"` and calling `$(".mylink")` with jQuery. Otherwise, your code will grow and it'll drive you crazy to change a single line